# Spotipy - get track ids from track names

Tags: python, spotipy

Usually, `spotipy` requires track IDs as parameters to be passed, in order to return track names.

Say I have two lists, **not** obtained from the Spotify API:

1. artists

   ```
   [u'Moses Sumney', u'Cherry Glazerr', u'Danny Brown', u'NxWorries']
   ```

   and their respective songs:
2. tracks

   ```
   [u'Lonely World', u"Told You I'd Be With the Guys", u'Really Doe [ft. Kendrick Lamar, Ab-Soul, and Earl Sweatshirt]', u'Lyk Dis']
   ```

Is it possible to do it the other way around and get track IDs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spotipy.search() is what you are looking for.

```
import spotipy
sp = spotipy.Spotify()

artist= 'Moses Sumney'
track= 'Lonely World'

track_id = sp.search(q='artist:' + artist + ' track:' + track, type='track')
```

This will return a list of songs that match the query, depending on how precise your search is will depend on how many results are returned.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask where you found documentation of the search query syntax? I couldn't figure it out until I found your answer

Comment: I just tested this and needed to add an auth token when creating the `sp` object: `sp = spotipy.Spotipy(auth='TOKEN')`.

Comment: Not clear to me how to extract the id from the returned JSON. You seem to have to use a list index which looks suspiciously like it might change position.

Comment: `trackId = track_id['tracks']['items'][0]['id']` did it for me