# How to fix basic Spotipy "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'str'" for the search function?

Tags: python, spotipy

I was trying the basic code on the following website (https://medium.com/@RareLoot/extracting-spotify-data-on-your-favourite-artist-via-python-d58bc92a4330) and I kept getting the mentioned error when I tried to run the first code under the "Set up your modules and variables" subheading.

I've found that the problem is with the search function, but don't know what it does.

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials #To access authorised Spotify data

client_id = {'some_numbers_and_letters'}
client_secret = {'some_numbers_and_letters'}
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager) #spotify object to access API

name='{Kendrick Lamar}'

sp.search(name)
```

It should be able to continue without an error, but that is not the case.

Comment: Not sure if there was a version change. But have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840319/spotipy-get-track-ids-from-track-names

Answer (score 1):

In the example you linked, the `{spotify client id}` and `{spotify secret id}` are meant as placeholders for strings.

In your code you don't create strings, but sets:

```
client_id = {'some_numbers_and_letters'}
client_secret = {'some_numbers_and_letters'}
```

This should be:

```
client_id = 'some_numbers_and_letters'
client_secret = 'some_numbers_and_letters'
```